How to generate textureless areas and disparity discontinuity areas of a disparity map
I want to use the Middlebury classic data set to test the performance of my own improved stereo matching algorithm. However, only the 2003 data sets (cones and teddy) on the official website contain textureless areas and parallax discontinuous areas.The official website of the data set for other years is not provided. How can I obtain it?
I tried to use left and right consistency to obtain the occlusion area, but it didn’t look consistent with what Middlebury’s official website provided.
